# Whats the best way to set the values of C3P0 parameters when it is in conjunction with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, configuration, c3p0

**First of all please note:** question is about values of parameters not methods of configuration. Also, my question is customized to my system requirement.

My system is going to be used by 20 concurrent users who make requests, and I believe max time that each query would be responded would be 300 seconds. Although I used JMeter and the application worked, I suspect the  value of idle_test_period should not be more than timeout value but in most tutorials online they are not. I am wondering if the following configuration is sufficient for my requirement. And whether the value of idle_test_period should be more than timeout or not?

```
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
```

Most websites configurations are the same such as : [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/) and [this](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4/HibernateC3P0.shtml)

Comment: Note that the downvoter is not necessarily the one who marked as duplicate. @Jarrod OP requests that you review.

Comment: if you are looking for guidance on what to actual set the values to instead of how to configure them, which wasn't clear before. That is **off-topic : opinion based / too broad** and ( formerly **too localized** ) anyway. **Nobody here can tell you what those values should be, that is what profiling, load testing and stress testing are for.** closed for dupe or closed for off topic, same difference.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thanks for your comment, as I mentioned in the question I used JMeter and application perfectly works; however, in contract with those provided well-known online tutorials I  found out those values should be changed. Thats why I am asking the question. I also explained my requirements in case it is needed by repliers.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a connection pool size is not a trivial thing to do. Any RDBMS will impose a max concurrent connnection limit, and I see you have already chosen a max size of 100 connections.

Typically, based on the RDBMS engine, the OS and the hardware you might get 100-300 max concurrent connections per DB node (matser/slave).

So if you plan to load balance this app, or run different apps all concurring for the limited db connections then things get really complicated.

I dedicated some time to find the best connection pool sizing strategy o here are my findings:

[The anatomy of Connection Pooling](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-connection-pooling)

[FlexyPool, reactive connection pooling](https://vladmihalcea.com/flexy-pool-reactive-connection-pooling)

[Professional connection pool sizing](https://vladmihalcea.com/professional-connection-pool-sizing)

So, I build an open source project called [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool) that allows you to:

1. monitor the connection pool behaviour (connection lease time, connection acquire time, retries, pool size grow)
2. gives you the possibility of finding the right pool size by using a pool increment on time threshold strategy

I hope it can help you finding the right pool size.

Comment: alrighty thanks for your answer, I read your articles, it seems FlexyPool is not finalized yet therefore it does not apply to my problem. What would be your suggestion about my idea of keeping the value of idle_test_period less than timeout value?

Comment: What do you mean FlexyPool is not finalized yet? We use it in production systems. The idle_test_period requires connections to be idle for that much before being physically closed. It's not related to a Tx timeout value.

Comment: I see, I though it is still under development.

Comment: It's as finalised as Hibernate is and Hibernate is in development too, for the next releases.